# etymology: to get rid of

Tags: etymology

*To get rid of* something according to OALD means to make oneself free of someone or something that is annoying. One can get rid of old useless
things by throwing them away or of bad habits.

There is also a verb *to rid*. etymonline has *to rid*, ca. 1200, meaning to clear (a space), to set free, to save. A connection is drawn to a verb in
Old Norse that means to clear land of obstructions, old variants of
Germanic languages are given, but modern German *Land roden* meaning to prepare a field or a path by eliminating trees is lacking.

According to the dictionary the expression *to get rid of something* is younger, dated around 1660.  My view is that *rid* in *to get rid of something* is connected with the verb free and the form freed, past participle or adjective
which we also have in modern German *befreit*.

One may imagine that a form like *rid* can develop from *freed* by dropping 
*f* and shortening the vowel.

I would not connect the expression *to get rid of something* with the idea of
clearing land as in German *roden*, I think a connection with *freed* is much
more plausible. But I think the derivations of the two word families *free*
and *to clear land* (as in German *roden*) have become so similar that in
English a separation is very difficult.

**Question:** What is more probable, the idea of clearing land or a connection with *freed*?

Comment: You write, "One may imagine that a form like rid can develop from freed by dropping f and shortening the vowel". As a theory that's fine as far as it goes, but do you have any actual _evidence_ for your supposition?

Comment: Right you are. Was too occupied with formulating my theory clearly and forgot my question. I'll add it.

Comment: You also need to look into the verb *redd* < OE *hrȩddan*. Disentangling that from the ModE *rid* < ME *ruden* < ON *ryðja* may not be completely possible.

Comment: @Erich Kowal  Would be fine if we had evidence for everything in etymology. Mostly etymological explanations are based on older word forms that have a similar shape, even when sometimes the semantic connection is dubious. And in such cases it is reasonable to look for other possibilities and for such hypotheses there is no evidence.

Comment: Do you have _any_ other examples of English losing an initial f in any word? I know of none. I can see no reason whatsoever that the adjective _rid_ should not be related to the verb _rid_ with the same basic meaning.

Comment: Would you think it impossible that an f before r could vanish? Such a historical sound change would be in the line  p b f v w cero.

Comment: No, not impossible at all—it has happened in many languages over time. But there is absolutely _no_ evidence that it has ever happened in English. On the contrary, there are lots and lots of words where it _hasn’t_ happened in English, including the word _free_ itself. Why would this change have randomly happened in this one single use (but no others) of this one single word (but no others)? Especially when there is already another word _rid_ that means the same thing. Occam's razor is firmly against it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  By chance I have found one example in the Scots Dictionary: red for afraid.http://www.dsl.ac.uk/dsl/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, I’m not sure folks’ll get away with blaming an *f* > ∅ loss on a Basque adstrate the way they’re always so quick to do when said loss happens in the circumpyrenean languages. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say no.

First of all, all the related words in the etymonline reference do lack the initial 'f', and your alternative theory will have to "cut" *rid* out of the very plausible migration of the word in that entry.

But more importantly, if you claim that rid was formed from "freed" by losing its initial *f* and a shortening of the vowel, then **why on earth** do we still use the word **freed** in its current form, *with* the initial *f* and *with* the long vowel? Actually, we also use expression like "get free of something", "I got freed of that burden".

How many examples do you have where a specific form of a word (here, the participle of a verb) undergoes *several* changes in pronunciation, and after those changes, is used *concurrently* with the exact original form of the same word, in the same meaning?

Now, if we were to see words like "riddom", "a rid man", "re drinks", I would be inclined to accept the possibility that those originated in an older form that had and extra *f* and a longer vowel.
Last time I checked, I didn't notice many of those forms though :)

Comment: It's a pity Low German, Frisian, Dutch, English Dialects and Scottish are not presented on the Internet in a way that it is possible to search for answers. Anyway, I think, if a formulation like *to become freed of sth* would have changed to *rid of sth" nobody would be able to say where it came from.

Comment: Of course, I mean Lowland Scots, not Scottish.

Comment: As for the Dutch, _free_ is _vrij_, and in all of its uses, it retains a long vowel and the initial v remains. In Dutch and German, _freed_ gets a prefix _be-_ (bevrijd, befreit), which also is not disappearing in any participles that have it.

Comment: From ʒour flyting, wald God, that I wer fred [: red]; Can anyone say what red in brackets after fred means? This is a quote from the Scots dictionary, to fre, number 2.

Comment: The [: red] means that *From ʒour flyting, wald God, that I wer fred* comes from a poem where *fred* rhymes with *red*.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of rid is "to remove". It has no realation to "freed". When you "get rid of" something, you are literally removing it. This may have a sense of being freeing, but it is not related etymologically.

Comment: Semantically a source that means *to become freed of sth* would be more plausible than a source that actually means *to remove trees and tree stumps from a wooded area*. But I'm almost sure that definite evidence for such a hyothesis is impossible to find.

Answer (score -1):

[From ʒour flyting, wald God, that I wer fred [: red];Dictionary of Scots, verb to fre](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/dsl/)

I have just found DSL, the Dictionary of the Scots Language.There I found the verb to fre with the past participle fred, meaning to free/freed. The past participle has compared to English freed a short vowel e. I think a change to i would easily be possible. It would be more difficult to find a reason why the f in fred/*frid should get lost. But particular historical change, especially when dialects get in contact with each other or transformation to another similar word are not impossible in etymology.
I can't understand every word of Scots, but as a German with some knowledge of Low German and Dutch I've got the gist of the entry. I think number 2 of the entry to fre is interesting.

What I would like is to get entries for German befreit von in various dictionaries as Scots, Low German, Frisian, Dutch and some English dialects of the north. But that would be a lot of research work.
Edit: Can anyone explain to me what *red* in brackets after *fred* means. Number 2 in the Scots dictionary:

Comment: Now I have made a mess of my post. The quote from the Scots dictionary that I wanted to put at the end of the post has appeared on top and has eliminated the link to the Scots dictionary. Here's the link again: http://www.dsl.ac.uk/dsl/

Comment: The notation "[: red]" means that in this quotation, *fred* comes from a poem where it rhymes with *red*. [See here](http://books.google.com/books?id=K1MrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22flyting,+wald+God%22&source=bl&ots=hxy087BWUP&sig=Y7utw5Lw0o0illSHWttZwO_0YKY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u7drU9i-I-vgsAT3noCwDA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22flyting%2C%20wald%20God%22&f=false)...

Comment: Also in the entry for *fred*, they have the notation "[: bred]". [See here](http://books.google.com/books?id=90orAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=%22Thocht+of+this+feir+thow+salbe+fred%22&source=bl&ots=DX8fmOdTCm&sig=oYyyS3LRtT0c5GPfclfDtmJnGsk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U7hrU8OAM6_lsASPkYH4Bw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Thocht%20of%20this%20feir%20thow%20salbe%20fred%22&f=false). These are incredibly useful for determining the pronunciation, but really don't advance your thesis at all. They don't indicate that the *"f"* could be dropped.